# If value of 1 table exists in the 2nd table, update the 2nd table value with sum of 1st and 2nd tables, else insert 1st table data to 2nd table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In SQL Server, I have tables `TAB` and `STG` as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE [Tab]
(
     [tab_Client] [VARCHAR](30) NULL,
     [tab_Security] [VARCHAR](30) NULL,
     [tab_Quantity] [FLOAT] NULL,
     [tab_Cost] [FLOAT] NULL
)

CREATE TABLE [Stg]
(
    [stg_client] [VARCHAR](30) NULL,
    [stg_security] [VARCHAR](30) NULL,
    [stg_Quantity] [FLOAT] NULL,
    [stg_Cost] [FLOAT] NULL
)
```

I need to either

1. if stg_client/stg_security doesn’t exist in the Tab table, insert the stg_Client/stg_Security data from Stg table to Tab table
2. if stg_client/stg_security exist in the Tab table:

   - update the Tab table’s tab_Quantity with the sum of Tab.tab_Quantity & Stg.stg_Quantity
   - update the Tab table’s tab_Cost with the sum of Tab.tab_Cost & Stg.stg_Cost

How can I do that ?

TAB table

```
Client  Security   Quantity     Cost
-------------------------------------
JP       L1         1           100
JP       L2         2           200
JP       L3         3           300
```

STG table

```
Client     Security   Quantity   Cost
-------------------------------------
JP         L1         10         1000
JP         L3         30         3000
JP         L4         40         4000
```

Desired result:

TAB table

```
Client    Security   Quantity     Cost
-----------------------------------------
JP        L1         11           1100  -> Sum of Tab and Stg table
JP        L2         2             200
JP        L3         33           3300  -> Sum of Tab and Stg table
JP        L4         40           4000  -> From Stg table
```

The MERGE works

```
MERGE TAB AS target
USING STG AS source ON target.tab_client = source.stg_client 
                    AND target.tab_security = source.stg_security

WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE 
        SET target.tab_quantity = source.stg_quantity + target.tab_quantity,
            target.tab_cost = source.stg_cost + target.tab_cost

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY target THEN
    INSERT (tab_client, tab_security, tab_quantity, tab_cost)
    VALUES (source.stg_client, source.stg_security, source.stg_quantity, source.stg_cost);
```

Thank you.

Comment: sounds like a MERGE statement in Oracle.  maybe something equivalent here.

Comment: There´s a MERGE statement in SQL Server. Otherwise, an UPDATE followed by an INSERT would do the trick.

Comment: ah..the merge statement works. I updated the post . Thank you

Comment: You should actually post your MERGE query as an answer, this might be useful for others...

Answer (score 0):

you could use  a join in updated

```
update  TAB 
set TAB.cost  = TAB.cost + STG.cost ,
    TAB.Quantity   = TAB.Quantity  + STG.Quantity     
from TAB  
INNER JOIN STG ON TAB.clinet = STG.client 
  AND   TAB.security = STG.security
```

Answer (score 0):

Another correct way to do this with SQL is with a LEFT OUTER JOIN for inserting the missing rows and an INNER JOIN for updating the existing rows -

Tip: Either Update matching before inserting missing or only insert the client/security fields in the insert statement to avoid updating the qty and cost of the newly inserted rows...

Here's a snippet:

````
UPDATE  t
SET tab_Cost = t.tab_Cost + s.stg_Cost ,
    tab_Quantity = t.tab_Quantity  + s.stg_Quantity     
FROM TAB t  
INNER JOIN STG s ON t.clinet = s.client AND t.security = s.security

INSERT INTO TAB (tab_client, tab_security, tab_quantity, tab_cost)
SELECT s.stg_Client, s.stg_Security, s.quantity, s.Cost
FROM STG s LEFT OUTER JOIN
TAB t ON t.clinet = s.client 
  AND  t.security = s.security
WHERE t.tab_client IS NULL```

(assuming tab_client is a non nullable field)
````